# How to remove "Bing" sign from Microsoft Launcher?

Tags: launcher, home-screen

I would like to have my home screen as clean as possible. Is there a way to remove the "Bing" icon from Microsoft Launcher (bottom right corner)?
I've deleted the search widget, fixed the dock in place - nothing helps.

I have:
Android 10.
King Kong Mini 2

[image]

Comment: That icon is part of the wallpaper and cannot be removed unless you change it to a custom wallpaper.

Comment: @JNic, what do you mean by wallpaper? the vulcano? it is custom and the icon is not part of it.

Comment: That wallpaper is not a custome wallpaper. @JNic is correct: When you use a wallpaper from Bing, you will see the bing logo (It's actually a button that shows info about the wallpaper). If you select your own image/photo/wallpaper, the bing logo/button will not be show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon is there because the wallpapers from the Microsoft Launcher is being pulled from Bing, so it has a watermark on it. You can't remove it unless you place your own custom wallpaper.

Comment: I set a wallpaper as home screen using Microsoft's launcher. That Bing logo was there as usual. I then switched to Nova Launcher. The wallpaper for home screen remained the same but the Bing logo was not there at all. BTW, I didn't pull wallpaper from cloud. I used the default wallpaper Microsoft launcher offered to me.

Comment: @Firelord, yeah, the Bign logo even moves with the dock for me when I turned it on and off, but once I used a 3rd party app to change wallpapers - it disappears